# Reset state object on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html5-history

I am using the History API. When the user is entering a page for the first time, I check if the state is null. If it is, then I replace the state with a state object. However, when I refresh the page, the state is not null anymore. It is the same state I set on the first page load. Is there a way to reset the state everytime someone refreshes the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `state` to reset every time the page loads (which will happen with a refresh):

```
window.onload = function() {
    state = null;
}
```

Also look at `beforeunload`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    state = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use the .unload event on windows. You are able to attach a handler to it too, just like window.onload. More here: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event.).

Comment: Worth referring to the example there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event#Examples.